# Ubuntu 18.04 boot from USB bricked asus rog B350-F motherboard

Tags: ubuntu, boot, liveusb, flashing

Already received a refund on the motherboard however,

I still do not have the  slightest idea why the board failed to boot the live USB and then Bricked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is *highly* unlikely booting an OS off of USB bricked the motherboard.  More than likely the motherboard was faulty and it was coincidence that it broke at that time.

Comment: I should correct myself while I attempted to install via USB to no avail. I then made the onboard hard drive a bootable device for the Ubuntu install which then may have killed the board.

Comment: @macimich Again, not in the least but probable.

Comment: Probable?  In what way?

Comment: @macimich mistype.  should be "not in the least *BIT* probable"